# Add AdMob banner without XML

Tags: android

Can I add AdMob banner without using XML layout? I have't found anything about this in the admob documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation I find nothing about using XML-Layout ([see here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addadview)).

However, registering the Activity in the Android Manifest and declaring your needed permissions must be done in XML.

Comment: I need ad banner WITHOUT using XML layout.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? There is no XML-Layout [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addadview).

Comment: LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

Comment: What's the problem about creating the `LinearLayout` in your Java-Code, too?

Comment: If you don't want to use any XML Layout stuff, you'll need to create every Widget using Java (like the used `LinearLayout`). The Docs are assuming that you already created a Layout XML with this `LinearLayout`. Using an XML Layout is really the better way.

Comment: I paint all by canvas. I create empty linearlayout, but as you see i get error on layout.addView(adView);

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that by using Window instance.

Here is the snippet of sample code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
mWindowParams.x = 0;
mWindowParams.y = 0;
mWindowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
mWindowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;                          
mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE                                 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
mWindowParams.windowAnimations = 0;
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _applicationActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

if (wm != null)
{
    wm.addView(_bannerAdView, mWindowParams);
}
```